# cv2: Can't create video of specific duration

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, psychopy, python

I'm having problem creating a webcam video in PsychoPy with a 30-sec duration. What happens instead is that the video is approximately 43 seconds in length. My code is as follows (slightly edited):

```
from psychopy import locale_setup, visual, core, event, data, gui, microphone
import cv2

#Set up Timer:
trialTimer = core.Clock()

#Begin Video Recording:
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0 + cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('{}.avi'.format(video_path),fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))

trialTimer.reset()

while trialTimer.getTime() < 30:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    out.write(frame)

#Stop video recording:
cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The video loops crisp (i.e. not too fast or slow), so I'm not quite sure what to adjust in order to get the video length down to 30 seconds.

Comment: can you show what `time` variable is and how you get this? It looks like it doesn't get updated therefore the while loop does not satisfy the exit condition

Comment: I'm doing the webcam video capture through PsychoPy, so the timer variable is a built-in function. I've edited the post to better reflect this.

Comment: I removed my answer as I know think I understand what the problem is (but not how you can fix it); basically the timer seems to be getting the time of the clock object not the video. See [documentation](https://www.psychopy.org/api/clock.html) for details

Comment: I changed the 3rd argument (fps) in the ```VideoWriter``` function to 29.4333, which makes the video 30 seconds now; however, it looks like it's in fast-forward. For now I  may just have to deal with this.

Comment: Your loop is constrained to last 30 s but the rate at which it iterates (and therefore samples images) is not constrained, nor synchronised to the frame rate of the camera. If you were using a PsychoPy window, injecting a `window.flip()` inside the loop would govern the loop to sample just one image from the camera per screen refresh (typically 60 Hz), or you could just grab an image on every second refresh, leading to recording video at 30 Hz, and so on.

Comment: Also see this suggested code from the PsychoPy site: https://www.psychopy.org/recipes/webcam.html

Comment: Thanks @MichaelMacAskill. I did view the linked webcam code, which was the inspiration for my code chunk, however I'm merely saving the frames to an .avi file and not presenting them at all. I'm having difficulty constraining the loop iteration to the frame rate -- inserting a ```win.flip()``` in the loop didn't resolve my issue. Is there another way to constrain the loop iteration to a specified rate?